# Problem sharing the same bluetooth speaker/headphones across multiple users

Tags: 18.04, sound, bluetooth

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and I've got a bluetooth speaker paired to the computer. It works fine for the first user logged in to use the speaker but, after the speaker has been paired, subsequent users that log in will see the speaker connected as a bluetooth device but are unable to use it as an audio device.

Forgetting and re-pairing the speaker doesn't give the audio device to the user that performed the re-pair.

The only workaround I've found so far is to kill the pid of the user that first connected to the speaker and then the subsequent user will see the speaker as an audio device. This doesn't work so great for my situation because I'm not always there to sudo the kill command for my kids, who tend to leave their sessions running and I don't want to teach them to reboot the machine to kick their family member's session out.

What other options are there?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: I am in this exact situation. Would love for the speaker to work for the currently active user.

Comment: Same situation over here. Repairing should resolve this but doesn't. I'll try killing the pid like you do because my solution so far is just to restart the computer and log everyone out.